# Create utility types in order to create object from two tuples

Tags: typescript

I have two basic tuples:

```
const tuples1 = ['a', 'b', 'c'] as const;
const tuples2 = [1, 2, 3] as const;
```

I want to create an object that will combine both:

```
const ResultMerge = {
  'a': 1,
  'b': 2,
  'c': 3
}
```

I use TypeScript so I would like to have a utility type to mapped types the work of the function.

The need of my solution is to retrieve the value of the second tuples base on the index of the first iteration.

Code:

```
type TuplesToObject<T extends readonly any[], U extends readonly any[]> = {
  [K in T[number]]: U[Extract<keyof T, K>[number]]
}
```

```
type TupleToObject<T extends readonly string[], U extends readonly any[]> = Record<T[number], U[Extract<keyof T, number>]>
```

But the result stay always the same for my utility type `TuplesToObject`. This is something like that:

```
{
  a: 3 | 1 | 2,
  b: 3 | 1 | 2,
  c: 3 | 1 | 2
}
```

And my purpose is to achieve this result

```
{
  a: 1 ,
  b: 2 ,
  c: 3
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/FAFwngDgpgBAKgVwgGynA9geQEYCsoDGIAPHDFAB4hQB2AJgM4wBOUAhnejcmDGzWADaAXQA0MAKrkqtRi3aduvfkOEA+GAF4YAb2AwYggNIwAljXiCaCALbYozYcIBckwQFEqzNkWIBrKDB0ADN4cSM1K1t7R2FgAF9gYAIuBhA+LUMAcjYs8SzsPJgsgizhPiYUmjSAbmTU9OxMwQBGcQAmcQBmcrZKhrqk8Gh4KDTMxBQ0LDxCEmGoEL5xBaXsNTqAek2DGAA9AH4k+ur0gldJ1AwcfF9V0LYVyEXQ9cy9Axys1zb9YsLXJ0-iVvjAuglgEA)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can [map over](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) the number-like keys of your tuples and use [key remapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as) to transform the index to the keys from the first [tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types):

```
type TupleToObject<
  K extends readonly PropertyKey[],
  V extends Record<keyof K, any>
> = {
    [I in `${number}` & keyof K as K[I]]: V[I]
  }
```

I've [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) `K` to be an array of keylike types, and `V` to be an object with at least the same indices as `K` (so that it will complain if `V` is shorter than `K`).

And we don't want to map over *all* the properties of the `K` tuple like `I in keyof T as K[I]` because that will end up including array method names like `"slice"`.  All we want are the "number-like" string indices such as `"0"` and `"1"` and `"2"`, corresponding to the positioned elements.  We can get those by [intersecting](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) `keyof T` with the *pattern template literal* (see [ms/TS#40598](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/40598)) `` `${number}` ``:

```
type NumberlikeKeys = `${number}` & keyof ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'];
// type NumberlikeKeys = "0" | "1" | "2" | "3" | "4"
```

Okay, let's test `TupleToObject<K, V>` out on your example:

```
const a = ['a', 'b', 'c'] as const;
const b = [1, 2, 3] as const;


type Test = TupleToObject<typeof a, typeof b>;
//   ^? type Test = { a: 1; b: 2; c: 3; }
```

Looks good!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAFwngDgpgBAKgVwgGynA9geQEYCsoDGIAPMDDANIxQAeIUAdgCYDOMATlAIZPoPJgYABXbpo7cBShgA2gF0ANGRgA1anUasYAJULp2TYgGtp6AGaUFMLgzAA+YHZgBeGAG9l5GQEkYASwYYAAMAEjcGBABbbCh2AF8gmAAyGBMwc0prNgofOTkALlVc5TjgUEhYADkomPZkPxMpMDZXUPCa2ITk1NMLGQByLn6rfuxhmH6Ccf6maah+uQBuYAB6FZhwaBhq6Nj6xukWmAAiAAZjmAAfE4BGC+vjgCZ7k4BmF+OAFmOygj4WEDWFwwAZDEZjEZTORZGB-BgA5ZwgEwbDAmQ3KyPKyvaFcNhIkDLMqbWBwKDI1yIFBoLB4QgkEkZLhWRkWbB2ZZrcgwAB6AH4NhV4OTAa43NZCjdFijCo9pQRCq9paUgA)

Comment: Thanks for the answer Jcalz. 
I love that cause I learned every days :)

Could you give me more explanation about the `V extends Record<keyof K, any>.

I understood we need to pass by K in order to find the index and retrieve the right information by V[I] but a I not sure why the readonly of a tuple be affect to a record of the K from the first one.

Comment: You want the second tuple to have at least the same indices as the first tuple; this will prevent you from writing `TupleToObject<["a","b","c"],[1,2]>` where the second tuple is too short