# Keys-Values Iteration in TypeScript Type

Tags: typescript, object, types, iteration, key-value

So I was making a cache manager with global cache object and I have its global object that will have "cached items", where the key of the property is "cached item name" and value is its own Map with specific value.

What am I trying is to iterate over a tuple of all keys in 1st parameter and assign the value from values tuple in 2nd parameter for that key in a separate type called `CachedItems`. It should be the type of `items` property of my cache manager class.

For example, type `CachedItems<['users', 'blacklist', 'something'], [User, Blacklist, Something]>`
should return this object:

```js
{
    users: Map<string, User>,
    blacklist: Map<string, Blacklist>,
    something: Map<string, Something>
}
```

One of my solutions was this one:

```js
type CachedItems<T extends readonly string[], V extends readonly any[]> = {
    [K in keyof T]: Record<T[K], Map<string, V[K]>>
}[number]
```

I expected this to iterate over T, set the property name for each key and set the Map value for the key, but either error was happening or types in all keys were `never`.

Any changes/variations of this solution have never brought me to the expected result.

Are there any possibilities to resolve this error and is my idea even possible to implement?

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mMzZQW) meet your needs?  If so I could write up an answer (although I answered [a *very* similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76137934/2887218) yesterday so I might just point you to that).  If not, what am I missing?

Comment: Okay, I closed it as a duplicate of the other one (it's essentially just one mapped tuple different, writing `Map<string, V[I]>` instead of `V[I]`) so my answer here would be nearly duplicate.  Good luck!